# Enable/Disable other inputs based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="tipoPre">Tipo de premio</label>
    <select id="tipoPre"><option value="Devolución de consumo">Devolución de consumo</option>
    <option value="Devolución de consumo de premio acumulado">Devolución de consumo de premio acumulado</option>
    <option value="Entrega individual">Entrega individual</option>
    <option value="Premio monetario">Premio monetario</option>
    </select>
    <label for="monDev">Monto devolucion</label>
    <select id="monDev">
    <option value="Monto acumulado">Monto acumulado</option>
    <option value="Monto del cupón">Monto del cupón</option>
    </select>
    <label for="numGanadores">Numero de ganadores</label>
    <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="numGanadores" name="numGanadores">
    <label for="numSuplentes">Numero de suplentes</label>
    <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="numSuplentes" name="numSuplentes">
    <label for="monMin">Monto minimo</label>
    <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="monMin" name="monMin">
    <label for="monMax">Monto maximo</label>
    <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="monMax" name="monMax">
    <label for="monPre">Monto premio</label>
    <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="monPre" name="monPre">
    <label for="acumulado">Acumulado a repartir</label>
    <input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="acumulado" name="acumulado">
</fieldset>
```

My jquery function:

```
function validateFieldsOnChange() {
    $("#monDev").prop('selectedIndex', -1);
    $("#tipoPre").prop('selectedIndex', -1);

    $("#tipoPre").change(function () {
        switch ($('#tipoPre option:selected').attr('value')) {
            case 'Entrega individual':

                $("#monDev, #monMin, #monMax, #monPre, #acumulado").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                break;
            case 'Premio monetario':

                $("#monDev, #monMin, #monMax, #acumulado").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                break;
            case 'Devolución de consumo':

                $("#monPre, #acumulado").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                break;
            case 'Devolución de consumo de premio acumulado':

                $("#monPre, #numGanadores").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
    });

}
```

When i use that code in a new form (add new record) works fine, but when i load it up to edit a existent record it doesnt work because the fields that should be enabled/disabled arent enabled or disabled

**EDIT:** The problem is not retrive the data to edit, when i retrieve the data i load it up the form if $(#tipoPre).val() = 'Entrega individual' the fields #monDev, #monMin, #monMax, #monPre, #acumulado should be **disabled** an **the rest** enabled

Comment: If you want things to be enabled/disabled based on data from the database, you need to set the controls to those states directly... the browser is not going to remember them between page loads. I presume all this is being driven by a server-side script?

Comment: @freefaller i just edited my post

Comment: This is a lot of code to read through, and most of it is irrelevant. Edit your question and keep the code examples short and to the point. You'll get more quality answers that way.

Answer (score 1):

Change event would be registered in `document.ready` instead of `validateFieldsOnChange` to produce the required results on change of `select`

```
$(function(){

function validateFieldsOnChange() {
    $("#monDev").prop('selectedIndex', -1);
    $("#tipoPre").prop('selectedIndex', -1);
});

$("#tipoPre").change(function () {
    switch ($('#tipoPre option:selected').attr('value')) {
        case 'Entrega individual':
            resetValues();
            $("#monDev, #monMin, #monMax, #monPre, #acumulado").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            break;
        case 'Premio monetario':
            resetValues();
            $("#monDev, #monMin, #monMax, #acumulado").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            break;
        case 'Devolución de consumo':
            resetValues();
            $("#monPre, #acumulado").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            break;
        case 'Devolución de consumo de premio acumulado':
            resetValues();
            $("#monPre, #numGanadores").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            break;
        default:

            break;
    });
   $("#sorPorFecha").click(function() {
    (typeof $("#sorPorFecha").attr('checked') != 'undefined') ?         $('#unicoPorFecha').removeAttr('disabled') : $('#unicoPorFecha').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       $('#unicoPorFecha').prop('checked', false);
    });

  });
```